# Why my NSDateFormatter returns null?

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

Why my NSDateFormatter returns null?
Here is my code:

```
  NSString *dateString = @"21-12-2012 11:05:15";
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
  NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
  dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
  NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
```

My `strDate` returns

```
21/12/2012
```

but when:

```
NSString *dateString = @"13-12-2012 13:17:58";
```

My `strDate` returns `null`

This is very weird, anyone has experienced the same?

Comment: The statement: `NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];` is unnecessary and the next statement overwrites it, simply use: `NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];`.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I will refactor my code. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use HH instead of hh.

hh usually is 12 hour time while HH is usually 24 hour time.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

A good official reference for this, [as linked by Apple themselves](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW13), is [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns). Another good table is [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime), as mentioned by Zaph.

Comment: See: [Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: Thanks cynicalme, but I will accept the other answer because it's the first answer..Thanks again anyway :)