# NSDateFormatter returns (null) on device but not on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm currently formatting a timer on the EST timezone to the devices timezone

Everything works perfectly on the Simulator and the timer converts but once I run it on my device it only returns a `(null)`.

The time string looks like this `11:00 AM ET`

```
NSString *timeString = time.time;

timeString = [timeString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" ET" withString:@""];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];
NSDate* dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeString];


NSDateFormatter* df_utc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df_utc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"]];
[df_utc setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];

NSDateFormatter* df_local = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df_local setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[df_local setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];

NSString *ts_utc_string = [df_utc stringFromDate:dateFromString];
NSString *ts_local_string = [df_local stringFromDate:dateFromString];

NSLog(@"UTC TIME: %@",ts_utc_string);
NSLog(@"LOCAL TIME: %@",ts_local_string);
```

On Device it NSLogs (null), but on the simulator it NSLogs the time.

Comment: Have you tried this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14303354/2298998 ?

Comment: Since the `AM` part for you date is localized you should tell the date  formatter in which language it is hoing to be: `[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];`

Comment: @rckoenes - That's not telling the date formatter which language, it's working around the iOS "feature" that mucks up date formatting if the device's 12/24 setting is set contrary to the current locale.

Comment: @HotLicks it also solves an issue when the `AM/PM` is different in the user locale.

Comment: @rckoenes you surprisingly got me moving forward, It's no longer returning (null), instead it's returning "02:45e.h." instead of "2:45 PM"